# Transform Data from Repository to Data for Viewmodel

Tags: java, android, firebase, mvvm, transformation

I want to implement MVVM into my app together with Firebase. I have read in many blogs, that Transformations are what I need, to connect the viewmodel with the repository, but I still cant really do it.

I want to update "callbackSignUp" with the value of "callback" in the repository after "callback" is updated. I know that probably my Transformation is wrong, but i would like some answers to:

1) What is the code needed here to run the app?

2) Do I need to add a function to the Transformation? And what is this function applied to?

3) Many use "input ->" after their source, but what does it mean? And do I need it in the function?

4) If possible please explain the map and switchmap function to me. After reading it many times, I still dont get it.

Thanks :)

Viewmodel

```
public class SignUpViewmodel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    public LiveData<Boolean> callbackSignUp = Transformations.map(userRepo.callback, input -> {
        if (input.booleanValue()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    public SignUpViewmodel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        userRepo = UserRepository.getInstance();

    }

    void signUp(String username, String email, String password, Date birthday, char gender, boolean receiveEmail){
        userRepo.signUp(email,password);
        Log.d(TAG, "signUp: COMPLETE");

    }


}
```

Repository

```
public class UserRepository {
    private static UserRepository instance = null;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public LiveData<Boolean> callback;

    public static synchronized UserRepository getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new UserRepository();
        }return instance;
    }


    public void signUp(String email, String password){
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: SUCCESS");
                            callback = new MutableLiveData<>(true);
                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: FAILED");
                            callback = new MutableLiveData<>(false);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }


}
```

Activity

```
model.callbackSignUp.observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, ""+ aBoolean, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I guess the following statement may be part of the problem: `callback = new MutableLiveData<>(true);` Here you assign a new instance to *callback*. The ViewModel is still observing the old instance. So it will never notice that there has been a change. Instead of creating a new instance of *callback*, use `postValue(...)` with the old instance

Answer (score 1):

`Transformations.map` is a utility function that help you to transform a LiveData of type a in a LiveData of type b. The a -> b conversion is done by the callback that you pass at the `map` function. `Tranformations.switchMap` is another utility function that returns a single LiveData that changes its source events when the trigger LiveData changes. For example: Imagine you have an app that manages different accounts. The current account is storend in a LiveData called `userLiveData`. Now you have a table in the db that for each account has the personal information of user and they have to be displayed on ui. You should write something like this:

```
infoLiveData = Tranformations.switchMap(userLiveData, user -> {
    return repository.getInfoLiveDataOf(user);
})
```

How you see, you have a single LiveData for the ui updates and every time userLiveData changes its value, infoLiveData switches its source events to the new LiveData returned by `repository.getInfoLiveData(user)`. This makes your code realy reactive. Now in your case you have different LiveData that should be mapped in a single LiveData. The use of `map` function is not util in your code. I think the best way is to use a single MutableLiveData where you put true or false when you call the signUp fuction without create each time a different LiveData.